# Request URL using Laravel Task Scheduling

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5

## Environment

- Laravel Version : **5.1.45 (LTS)**
- PHP Version : **5.6.1**

---

## Description

I'm trying to hit a certain route every minute.

---

## Attempt

I've tried

```
$schedule->exec('curl '.env('APP_URL').'fbwifi/acl_update')->everyMinute()
        ->sendOutputTo(public_path().'/tasks/log.txt');
```

---

**Kernel.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->exec('curl '.env('APP_URL').'fbwifi/acl_update')->everyMinute()
        ->sendOutputTo(public_path().'/tasks/log.txt');
    }
}
```

Is what I did is the best way to make a GET to a route ? or is there a better way I should look into ?

Answer (score 4):

**Update with Possible Solution:**

If your controller is in default namespace, then you can use it by using full namespaced path in call function of schedule.

**Default Namespace:** App\Http\Controllers

Assuming **fbwifi** is your controller & **acl_update** is your method.

```
$schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\fbwifi@acl_update')
         ->everyMinute()
         ->sendOutputTo(public_path().'/tasks/log.txt');
```

---

I would like to go with best practice, by creating separate class described as per following article.

https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-cronjobs-with-laravel/

1) Create Command Class -> Provide Signature and Description of command

```
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'sms:birthday';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description.';
```

2) Define your handle() method into that command class

```
public function handle()
{
  User::whereBirthDate(date('m/d'))->get(); 

  foreach( $users as $user ) {
    if($user->has('cellphone')) {
    SMS::to($user->cellphone)
       ->msg('Dear ' . $user->fname . ', I wish you a happy birthday!')
       ->send();
    }   
}  

$this->info('The happy birthday messages were sent successfully!');

}
```

3) Add that command class in $commands array of ConsoleKernal extended class

```
protected $commands = [
     // ...
     'App\Console\Command\HappyBirthday'
];
```

4) Schedule your command as per your requirement like below.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{   
  $schedule->command('sms:birthday')->daily();
}
```

Comment: You didn't answer my question, please update your answer.

Comment: best way to **make a GET** to a route/url ? I didn't ask anything about SMS or how to make a Task Scheduler ...

Comment: @ihue Answer is updated. Please check now and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

First of all when ever you are asking a question like "How to call one controller function from another one, You should revisit your code to separate the task specific logic and extract it in a different class file. Then you can use the new class and call it where ever you want, like in a cron job.

Since you are looking to make Plain old curl request function, creating a function in helper file is handy

```
function http_response($url, $status = null, $wait = 3) 
{ 
    $time = microtime(true); 
    $expire = $time + $wait; 

    // we fork the process so we don't have to wait for a timeout 
    $pid = pcntl_fork(); 
    if ($pid == -1) { 
        die('could not fork'); 
    } else if ($pid) { 
        // we are the parent 
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
        $head = curl_exec($ch); 
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
        curl_close($ch); 

        if(!$head) 
        { 
            return FALSE; 
        } 

        if($status === null) 
        { 
            if($httpCode < 400) 
            { 
                return TRUE; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                return FALSE; 
            } 
        } 
        elseif($status == $httpCode) 
        { 
            return TRUE; 
        } 

        return FALSE; 
        pcntl_wait($status); //Protect against Zombie children 
    } else { 
        // we are the child 
        while(microtime(true) < $expire) 
        { 
        sleep(0.5); 
        } 
        return FALSE; 
    } 
}
```

But if you want to have something with Object and API then you might wanna use 
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

If you don't have composer

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

If you already have composer installed globally

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Then you can make a request

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user', [
    'auth' => ['user', 'pass']
]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();
// 200
echo $res->getHeaderLine('content-type');
// 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $res->getBody();
// {"type":"User"...'

// Send an asynchronous request.
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org');
$promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
});
$promise->wait();
```

And make other kinds of requests like

```
$response = $client->get('http://httpbin.org/get');
$response = $client->delete('http://httpbin.org/delete');
$response = $client->head('http://httpbin.org/get');
$response = $client->options('http://httpbin.org/get');
$response = $client->patch('http://httpbin.org/patch');
$response = $client->post('http://httpbin.org/post');
$response = $client->put('http://httpbin.org/put');
```